Cache Storage vs IndexDB for short lived data
I need to handle a 500MB file upload where the user may be redirected to a login page and later return to resume the upload. To store the file temporarily, options like IndexedDB or CacheStorage seem viable, but they may have limitations with large files and short-lived data. The FileSystemAccess API was considered but isn't widely supported across browsers. What is the best solution for this use case?"
Which is better in terms of speed and security for temporarily storing a 500MB file: IndexedDB or CacheStorage?

is 500MB typical - or worst-case-scenario? Can't you trigger the auth check (and so do the login) before this?

Also, what about OPFS?

Also, can't you run a ServiceWorker? That way you can handle activity (incl. uploads, etc) in the background regardless of the user's browser getting redirected or having multiple windows/tabs open, etc.

The problem is that for certain file extensions, authentication is required, which can only be checked after the user uploads the file. we must pause the further operations on it and resume it when the user returns.
The worst-case scenario involves handling files up to 500MB. While the OPFS (Origin Private File System) could be a good fit for such cases, it is not yet supported by all browsers.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I need to know which method is preferred for storing short lived data cache storage or indexDB as I can't use OPFS due to limited support

IndexedDB, according to this documentation is best suited for large data structures.
The maximum storage allowed is based on the browser, see storage limits documentation
